# How to draw a spiral in phase portrait?

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

I am aware of easily drawing a spiral in the note of nonlinear dynamics.
Here are some examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: -1: No research effort.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: the above is just a statement…not a question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use TikZ. Here is an example:

[image]

But I never used it before, so maybe there is a better method than gluing arrows together, here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,compat=newest}

%for arrows in the middle of the line
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  %straight lines
  \draw[->-=.4] (0,0) to (-1,0);
  \draw[->-=.6] (0,-1) to (0,0); 
  %arcs on the left
  \draw[->-=.5] (-0.3,1) to [out=-90,in=0] (-1,0.3);
  \draw[->-=.5] (-0.3,-1) to [out=90,in=0] (-1,-0.3);
  %big circle from the bottom to the top
  \draw[->-=.5] (0.3,-1) to [out=90,in=200] (0.8,-0.3);
  \draw (0.8,-0.3) to [out=20, in =-90] (1.5,0.5) to [out=90, in=0] (0.7,1.3) to [out=180,in=90] (0,0.5);
  \draw[->-=.2]  (0,0.5) to (0,0);
  %inward spiral
  \draw[->-=.8]  (0,0) to (0.5,0);
  \draw[->] (0.5,0) to [out=0, in=-90] (1.1,0.5) to [out=90, in=0] (0.7,0.9) to [out=180, in=90] (0.4,0.6) to [out=-90, in=180] (0.6,0.4) to [out=0,in=-90] (0.75,0.6);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Check you the [very minimal introduction to TikZ](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf). In order to get the arrows in the middle of a line, I googled "tikz arrows in the middle of line".

Comment: Without code it's worth just about nothing.

Comment: I thought, this more a general question, since the original post had no code in it either. Added the code now.

Comment: Wow! Thanks you! It looks really great! I guess I need to spend some time on learning the tikz...